# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) in hwuiTask1

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview, exoplayer, android-native-library

My Android app is crashing with the below error. I don't have much knowledge of native.

My app is a digital signage app in which Video and Image is running alternatively in a loop. For playing the video exoplayer is used and for Image rendering Glide is used.

```
16262-16427/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x10 in tid 16427 (hwuiTask1), pid 16262 (e.signage)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.262 17965-17965/? I/crash_dump32: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
2021-02-02 19:07:31.262 3281-3281/? I//system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 16427
2021-02-02 19:07:31.263 17965-17965/? I/crash_dump32: performing dump of process 16262 (target tid = 16427)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.313 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2021-02-02 19:07:31.313 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Amlogic/franklin/franklin:9/PPR1.180610.011/20200313:userdebug/test-keys'
2021-02-02 19:07:31.313 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2021-02-02 19:07:31.313 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
2021-02-02 19:07:31.313 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG: pid: 16262, tid: 16427, name: hwuiTask1  >>> com.digital.signage <<<
2021-02-02 19:07:31.313 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x10
2021-02-02 19:07:31.313 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
2021-02-02 19:07:31.313 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     r0  00000000  r1  9060c540  r2  8c8e7324  r3  00000000
2021-02-02 19:07:31.313 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     r4  8c8e7358  r5  00000000  r6  8c8e7330  r7  1e137a67
2021-02-02 19:07:31.313 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     r8  00000000  r9  8c8e7420  r10 00000001  r11 00000000
2021-02-02 19:07:31.313 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     ip  ae9f6e20  sp  8c8e7318  lr  ae9dc62f  pc  ae9dc632
2021-02-02 19:07:31.576 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2021-02-02 19:07:31.576 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0005d632  /system/lib/libgui.so (android::SurfaceComposerClient::Transaction::getLayerState(android::sp<android::SurfaceControl> const&)+322)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.576 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0005d9a3  /system/lib/libgui.so (android::SurfaceComposerClient::Transaction::deferTransactionUntil(android::sp<android::SurfaceControl> const&, android::sp<android::Surface> const&, unsigned long long)+22)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000a4f35  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::nativeDeferTransactionUntilSurface(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long long, long long, long long, long long)+64)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 003cdab9  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ab000) (android.view.SurfaceControl.nativeDeferTransactionUntilSurface+152)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 009b6d13  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ab000) (android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction.deferTransactionUntilSurface+114)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00b0e759  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ab000) (android.view.SurfaceView.applySurfaceTransforms+112)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 00b10bc9  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x3ab000) (android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurfacePosition_renderWorker+240)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 00417d75  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 003f12e7  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+226)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 000a1031  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+136)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00350a6d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+52)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 00351a15  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+316)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 0027872f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+482)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 000792d3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallVoidMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+38)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 000a0d9b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZZN7androidL46android_view_RenderNode_requestPositionUpdatesEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectxS3_EN26SurfaceViewPositionUpdater21doUpdatePositionAsyncExiiii+126)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 000a0f0d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcINS_6__bindINS_8__mem_fnIMZN7androidL46android_view_RenderNode_requestPositionUpdatesEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectxS8_E26SurfaceViewPositionUpdaterFvxiiiiEEEJPS9_xiiiiEEENS_9allocatorISE_EEFvvEEclEv+52)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 00374b9d  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CacheManager::SkiaTaskProcessor::onProcess(android::sp<android::uirenderer::Task<bool>> const&)+14)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 003733cb  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::TaskProcessor<bool>::process(android::sp<android::uirenderer::TaskBase> const&)+38)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 003412ad  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::TaskManager::WorkerThread::threadLoop()+84)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #19 pc 0000c1bf  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+286)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #20 pc 0006f05f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+82)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #21 pc 00063c15  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+22)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.577 17965-17965/? A/DEBUG:     #22 pc 0001e065  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+22)
2021-02-02 19:07:31.609 17965-17965/? I/crash_dump32: type=1400 audit(0.0:2541): avc: denied { read } for name="497f16eba00a1f650f784516b3bb741a8e18b02be63b411835b0d8b85e6e0e24.0" dev="mmcblk0p20" ino=1181128 scontext=u:r:crash_dump:s0:c53,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c53,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=1
2021-02-02 19:07:31.609 17965-17965/? I/crash_dump32: type=1400 audit(0.0:2542): avc: denied { open } for path="/data/data/com.digital.signage/cache/image_manager_disk_cache/497f16eba00a1f650f784516b3bb741a8e18b02be63b411835b0d8b85e6e0e24.0" dev="mmcblk0p20" ino=1181128 scontext=u:r:crash_dump:s0:c53,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c53,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=1
2021-02-02 19:07:31.609 17965-17965/? I/crash_dump32: type=1400 audit(0.0:2543): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/data/data/com.digital.signage/cache/image_manager_disk_cache/497f16eba00a1f650f784516b3bb741a8e18b02be63b411835b0d8b85e6e0e24.0" dev="mmcblk0p20" ino=1181128 scontext=u:r:crash_dump:s0:c53,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c53,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=1
```

Please guide me with the reason and solution for this error.

Comment: Hi @a.prateek same error I am also facing, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Hi @a.pateek.. any solution you found on the same ??

Comment: [user16558522](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16558522) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68585212) saying "please see [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139111930](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139111930), should help. Also has a fix on android side:[https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/ diff on commit 005c63e8c6e6e5](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/005c63e8c6e6e5b312dc9c4631c57fb12224df30%5E%21/#F0)"